# NVI based NAT on Cisco ISR terrible performance

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-isr

I am trying to experiment with a Cisco ISR 1841 and have configured NAT on the device. The intention is to simulate it being a broadband router. I understand that this is not the best performing router around and has a max throughput of 40Mbps.

With scenario (A) I have configured classic inside/outside NAT with zone-based firewall. Overall the throughput drops to about 30Mbps when trying to speed test traffic from one end to the other through the router. Not to bad considering the age of the router but with this setup I think that CEF switching is still working. The issue with this setup is it does not officially support hair pinning when trying to port forward.

With scenario (B) I have configured the same as above except it is using NVI instead of inside/outside classic NAT. Doing the same speed test, the performance tanks to between 8Mbps and 10Mbps with the CPU usage going near 100%. Almost 50% of that going to the process switching process even though CEF is still enabled. The process in question is called `"IP Input"` when using `"sh proc cpu sorted"`

I have read similar stories for newer Cisco ISR devices like the 1900 and 2900 series routers. Is it just a fact that NVI based NAT cannot make use of CEF switching or is there some special configuration that needs to be done? Or is NVI in hardware only supported on the obscenely big router models?

**My NVI example**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.1
 description outside
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.248
 ip nat enable
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 zone-member security outside


interface FastEthernet0/1.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat enable
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 zone-member security inside


ip nat source list nat-access interface FastEthernet0/0.1 overload

ip access-list extended nat-access
 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

**sh cef int f0/0.1**

```
FastEthernet0/0.1 is up (if_number 5)
  Corresponding hwidb fast_if_number 5
  Corresponding hwidb firstsw->if_number 2
  ICMP redirects are always sent
  Per packet load-sharing is disabled
  IP unicast RPF check is disabled
  Input features: Stateful Inspection, Virtual Fragment Reassembly, IPSec input classification, Virtual Fragment Reassembly After IPSec Decryption
  Output features: Post-routing NAT NVI Output, Stateful Inspection, IPSec output classification, CCE Post NAT Classification, Firewall (firewall component), IPSec: to crypto engine, Post-encryption output features
  IP policy routing is disabled
  Hardware idb is FastEthernet0/0
  Fast switching type 1, interface type 18
  IP CEF switching enabled
  IP CEF switching turbo vector
```

IOS Version: (C1841-ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.1(4)M10

(EDIT) edited with iOS version and cef interface output

Thanks